# How to share data in go‘s middlewares efficiently?

Tags: go

How to share data in go‘s middlewares efficiently?

Known solutions:

1. Global map[interface{}]interface{}, it need type assertion and mutex, it is not i want.
2. Standard library: **x/net/context**, but I can not visit the **golang.org**(blocked by Great Firewall of China), 
   can somebody provides some examples or articles? Thanks.

Could somebody tell me what other efficient solution?

Comment: run `godoc -http=:6060` then navigate to localhost:6060 you will have godocs to lookup context (context is the best choice)

Comment: i have used `gin-gonic/gin` for middlewares and used `func (c *Context) Set(key string, value interface{}) { ... }` to store `value` by `key` on the context, and `func (c *Context) Get(key string) (value interface{}, exists bool) { ... }` to look them up. You may need to type cast `value`

Comment: This is the discussion thread about the new net/context implementation in go 1.7.1 https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14660 . If you cannot get 1.7.1 yet here is a variation which is easy and fast. https://github.com/goodfoo/requestcontext/blob/master/example/example.go

Comment: Viper can be nice to: https://github.com/spf13/viper/